# Is it Possible to Invoke Cloud Run with Gmail-Auth?

Tags: google-oauth, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-dns, google-cloud-networking, google-vpc

I want to ask a conceptional question and take advices about possible system design if possible.

The plan is basically authenticating specific Gmail users to use my serverless backend application. I'm thinking about either forwarding users directly to my VPC or I can authenticate them in my host-provider server and then after forward them to the VPC (or directly Cloud Run service?).

I'd be really glad if someone experienced can lead me about concepts and suggest design ideas about this.

Comment: What type of authentication do you have with your gmail user? OAuth token, cookies,???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by@John Hanley, your question has concepts that do not exist.

**To invoke Cloud Run authentication to specific users to use your serverless backend application, go through below required possible systems designs :**

1)Initially design how to describe [IAM roles](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles) that are associated with Cloud Run, and list the permissions that are contained in each role.

2)Design how to secure and Configure Cloud Run to limit access to [Cloud Run service with Identity aware Proxy(IAP).](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/enabling-cloud-run#enabling)

3)Design how to [create a Serverless VPC Access connector](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc#before_you_begin) and also know how to use [IAP for TCP forwarding within a VPC Service Controls perimeter](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/securing-tcp-with-vpc-sc#before_you_begin).

4)Step by step implementation of how to use IAP to secure portal access without using a Virtual Private Network (VPN). IAP simplifies implementing a zero-trust access model and takes less time than a VPN for remote workers both on-premises and in cloud environments with [a single point of control for managing access to your apps](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/secure-serverless-application-with-identity-aware-proxy#0).

Answer (score 0):

Solution to the what I had in mind was could be accomplished by Identity-Aware Proxy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).